# How do I include Custom Object Actions in a Managed Package?

Tags: salesforce1-app, package, action

I have a custom object with a page layout and an object-specific action. I have included the action, listed under Salesforce1 Actions in the Page Layout editor, in the Actions in the Salesforce1 Action Bar section. Everything works fine when using the action in Salesforce1 in my developer org. When I package up (beta release) the custom object and attempt to install it in another developer org, I receive the following error:

```
This app can't be installed.
There are problems that prevent this package from being installed.
(Alert__c-Alert Layout) In field: QuickAction - no QuickAction named mynamesp__Alert__c.Disable_Users_Action found
```

From what I have read, it sounds like the Action should just be included along with the Page Layout. Am I missing something? Also, in Setup, the page layout has an icon indicating it is part of the package; the action does not. Thanks!